# how to dynamically change the textview height and cell height according to the text length without the scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dynamic, uitextview

this is my code that shows data in table,my complete data is not showing in cell.
1st image is when i set scrollable to no ,2nd image when i do not set scrollable.i am a beginner.plz help me out of this.

[image][image]

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
[table beginUpdates];
[table  endUpdates];
}

-(void)createdatabase{

BOOL success;

NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [filemanager fileExistsAtPath:datapath];

if (success)return;

NSString *databasefromapp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataname];

[filemanager copyItemAtPath:databasefromapp toPath:datapath error:nil];

}

-(void)getdatabase{

eventitleary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
eventdescary = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
eventimgary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

sqlite3 *dataname1;

if (sqlite3_open([datapath UTF8String],&dataname1) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement;

    sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM photography_events";


    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataname1, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            // Read the data from the result row

            NSString *str_title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

            [eventitleary addObject:str_title];

            NSString *str_desc = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

            [eventdescary addObject:str_desc];

            NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(compiledStatement, 2) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(compiledStatement, 2)];
            [eventimgary addObject:data];

        }

    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", eventitleary);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;

 }
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return eventitleary.count;
 }

 -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *cellidenti = @"CellIdenti";

TableViewCell2 *cell = (TableViewCell2*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidenti];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell2" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.eventitlelbl.text = [eventitleary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.eventdesc.text = [eventdescary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventdesc.editable = NO;
//cell.eventdesc.scrollEnabled = NO;
[cell.eventdesc sizeToFit];

frame = cell.eventdesc.frame;

frame.size = cell.eventdesc.contentSize;

cell.eventdesc.frame = frame;

NSData *dataimg = (NSData*)[eventimgary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.eventimg.image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataimg];

return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// Return the height with a bit of additional padding space
return frame.size.height + 300;
}
```

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by adaptive layout. [Check this awesome tutorial if you are working with autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift). Else you can set dynamic tableView cell height by calculating the height in which your text will fit.

You can calculate height of text by using below method. Pass text, required font and width of your textview.

```
-(CGFloat)heightForText:(NSString*)text withFont:(UIFont *)font andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
   CGSize constrainedSize = CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT);
   NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName,nil];
   NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attributesDictionary];
   CGRect requiredHeight = [string boundingRectWithSize:constrainedSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
   if (requiredHeight.size.width > width) {
    requiredHeight = CGRectMake(0,0,width, requiredHeight.size.height);
   }
   return requiredHeight.size.height;
}


-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return [self heightForText:@"your text view text for this row" withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16] andWidth:320];
}
```

Comment: downvoter can you please give a reason for your down vote ?

Comment: Great solution to add a textview to a cell with dynamic height.

Answer (score 1):

i just got it, i wanted to do it dynamically rather than using auto layout,here is my code.Hope in future it works out to anyone.
[image]