# How to calculate TextView height base on text

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am using the code below for calculate the height of text, then set this height for `UILabel` and `UITextView`

```
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(300, CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSString *message = @"The Internet connection appears to be offline.";

NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGSize boundingBox = [message boundingRectWithSize:targetSize
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FontOpenSanWithSize(14)}
                                              context:context].size;

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
// it will return size:width = 299 and size height 20
// => if I use this height and set for UILabel, it can display full content
// => if I use this height and set for UITextView, it can not display full content
```

It's work perfect for `UILabel` but for `UITextView` sometime it calculate wrong.
I think the problem happened because the padding (left, right) of `UITextView` is bigger than `UILabel`.
So how can I calculate the correct size of text for display in `UITextView`. Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Like the description image below
With the same size (300), same font, same text but the `UITextView` display in 2 lines, but `UILabel` in 1 lines.
And my code for calculate height return 20, it not enough for display in 2 lines, so the `UITextView`can not display full content

**The reason why I need to calculate the height of `UITextView` base on text** because my `UITextView` is in a popup.
And the popup height will depend on the `TextView` height

[image]

Comment: you can bind textview height constant and then use it to update height i guess

Comment: Just visit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678779/how-to-dynamically-change-the-textview-height-and-cell-height-according-to-the-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I size a UITextView to its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Answer (score 13):

There are two things you can try:

1. Set `textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`
2. Set `textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0`

With these operations you can get rid of all the padding in the textView and when its width matches with the label's one the heights are also the same.

Here's a sample code you can place in an empty viewController and test it yourself:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSString *text = @"The internet connection appears to be offline.";
    CGFloat width = 100.f;

    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, width, 300)];
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:12.f];
    textView.text = text;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 + width, 20, width, 300)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-Regular" size:12.f];
    label.text = text;
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    // Getting rid of textView's padding
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;

    // Setting height of textView to its contentSize.height
    CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
    textViewFrame.size = textView.contentSize;
    textView.frame = textViewFrame;

    // Setting height of label accorting to it contents and width
    CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
    labelFrame.size = [label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, HUGE_VALF)];
    labelFrame.size.width = width;
    label.frame = labelFrame;

    NSLog(@"Label bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label.bounds));
    NSLog(@"TextView bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(textView.bounds));

    // Visualizing final effect with borders
    textView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
}
```

Console output:

```
2016-09-01 14:29:06.118 stack39268477[943:243243] Label bounds: {{0, 0}, {100, 66}}
2016-09-01 14:29:06.119 stack39268477[943:243243] TextView bounds: {{0, 0}, {100, 66}}
```

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to calculate Height of `UITextview` based on text.

Just change frame and set height like this:

```
textview.size.height = textview.contentSize.height;
```

This is easy solution. I hope this helps you.

Comment: my case is different so I can not use this way. please check my update

Answer (score 7):

This calculates the size of any string, whether or not you put them in a text view.

```
let frame = NSString(string: yourText).boundingRect(
    with: CGSize(width: yourDesiredWidth, height: .infinity),
    options: [.usesFontLeading, .usesLineFragmentOrigin],
    attributes: [.font : yourFont],
    context: nil)

let height = frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers here are hints into the right direction :-)

So, just to sum it all up...

**UITextView** uses a **NSTextContainer** (inside a private API _UITextContainerView) to do the real layout work.
This NSTextContainer(View) may have insets to the surrounding UITextView, which are set by UITextView's **textContainerInset** property.
The defaults for this insets seem to be:

- top: **8**
- left: **0**
- bottom: **8**
- right: **0**

The NSTextContainer itself may have additional left and right insets for the text itself. These insets are set in NSTextContainer's **lineFragmentPadding** property.

- The default for this is **5.0**.

As a result, when calculating the optimum frame size for a **UITextView** based on the boundingRect for some text inside that UITextView, we have to take all these insets into account:

```
CGSize reservedSpace = CGSizeMake((textView.textContainerInset.left + (2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding) + textView.textContainerInset.right),
                                  (textView.textContainerInset.top + textView.textContainerInset.bottom));
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake((300.0 - reservedSpace.width), CGFLOAT_MAX);
NSString* message = @"The Internet connection appears to be offline.";

NSStringDrawingContext* context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGSize boundingBox = [message boundingRectWithSize:targetSize
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FontOpenSanWithSize(14)}
                                              context:context].size;

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width),
                         (ceil(boundingBox.height) + reservedSpace.height));
```

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

A *classic* hack I've used to do this is create a function that takes the `String` as a parameter.  Within the function it generates a label with the width required, infinite number of lines, and a height of "too much". Then apply `sizeToFit()` on the label and return the height of the frame.

```
func calculatedHeight(for text: String, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width,
                                      height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```

The returned height can be applied to a `UITextField` height anchor. Though I do recommend calculating the width dynamically based on screen size, but that's up to you.

Answer (score -1):

self.textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
self.textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0

In storyboard or xib mark textview height >=0.

If you are using text view with table view. 
Calculate cell height according to content, textview will adjust it's space.