# getting the height of the custom cell in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a bubble chat like application. I created custom functions for the receiving and sending bubble chats.

After creating them, I've added them into the cells that I've created using the UITableView.

However, I am not able to set the height of the cell, depending on the height of the custom cell itself.

For example, some text passed in could be longer than the one before.

Thus I can't seem to set each cell according to the custom bubble chat height.

Please help!

**This are my tableview functions**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrMsg.count
}

// second
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100
}

// lastly created
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath)

    if arrMsg[indexPath.row]["type"] as! String == "outgoing" {
        cell.contentView.addSubview(createOutGoingBubble(msg: arrMsg[indexPath.row]["message"] as! String))
    }
    if arrMsg[indexPath.row]["type"] as! String == "incoming" {
        cell.contentView.addSubview(createIncomingBubble(mymsg: arrMsg[indexPath.row]["message"] as! String))
    }
    return cell
}
```

[This is how it looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9aWC.png)

How do I set the height of the cell according to the custom bubble created inside the heightforrowat function?

Probably using the line to find the height and return it:

```
arrMsg[indexPath.row]["message"] as! String == "outgoing"
```

**This is my function to create the custom bubble chats to be added into the tableviewcell

```
func createOutGoingBubble(msg:String) -> UIView {

    let subV = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))

    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = msg

    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: 0.66 * view.frame.width,
                                height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = msg.boundingRect(with: constraintRect,
                                       options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                       attributes: [.font: label.font],
                                       context: nil)
    label.frame.size = CGSize(width: ceil(boundingBox.width),
                              height: ceil(boundingBox.height))

    let bubbleSize = CGSize(width: label.frame.width + 28,
                            height: label.frame.height + 20)

    let outgoingMessageView = UIImageView(frame:
        CGRect(x: view.frame.width - bubbleSize.width - 20,
               y: bubbleSize.height - 25,
               width: bubbleSize.width,
               height: bubbleSize.height))

    let bubbleImage = UIImage(named: "outgoing")?
        .resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 17, left: 21, bottom: 17, right: 21),
                        resizingMode: .stretch)
        .withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)

    outgoingMessageView.image = bubbleImage
    outgoingMessageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.40 , green: 0.71, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1)

    subV.addSubview(outgoingMessageView)

    label.center = outgoingMessageView.center

    subV.addSubview(label)

    return subV
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you bring the code into the question? thanks in advance.

Comment: done with the editing! the image of my simulator is there too. @benc

Comment: **Tip:** You should be adding views in the `cellForRowAt` method! You should be creating a custom cell class and having the bubble there and then adding just the text in `cellForRowAt`. Also, automatic dimension should take care of height if you have set up the constraints of the bubble relative to the `contentView` of the cell.

Comment: thanks @RakeshaShastri , but I am trying to only use one ViewController and populate everything in there.

Comment: @IskandarSalleh Unless you are using the default labels and image views in a `UITableViewCell`, you should be creating a custom table view cell everytime. _" I am trying to only use one ViewController and populate everything in there."_ Why? Also i am not asking you to create a new view controller. Just a custom `UITableViewCell`. You should look up some tutorial about table views. You do not seem familiar with how to use them.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri ive edited my question

Comment: Will you consider using constraints and have a dynamic cell height?
You may want to take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717173/uitableviewcell-auto-height-based-on-amount-of-uilabel-text

Comment: thank you for the response @VictorKwok however that will not work as I'm using a custom subview and my cell is currently empty and has nothing inside it. is there any other way?

Comment: If you do not want to use constraints, you can try to make a function (maybe called heightForBubbleWithText) that calculates the height required for the cell in your custom cell subclass. Then in the cellForRowAt method, call this method with the text as parameter and return the height.

Comment: But actually even using a custom subview you may also use constraints to make a cell with dynamic height

Comment: @VictorKwok I have no idea how to do it as im still new to swift. is there any way where you could show?

Comment: and idea how I could use the  -arrMsg[indexPath.row]["message"] as! String == "outgoing"- method to find the height and place it in the heightforrowat function? @VictorKwok

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268477/how-to-calculate-textview-height-base-on-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Autolayout for the same and get free from all the coding part. Just set the constraint of the inner view in association with the cell and then right the following code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:ChatSenderTableViewCell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatSenderTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ChatSenderTableViewCell)!

        cell.LabelChatMessage.text = "Your Message"
        cell.LabelChatMessage.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.LabelChatMessage.sizeToFit()

        return cell

}
```

I am using a custom cell name ChatSenderTableViewCell to create a bubble like effect containing a label for messages send or receive.

Answer (score 0):

Use label inside of view and use margin from top and bottom according to your desire. Also, you need to make 0 number of lines in UIlabel. you can do it by using label.numberoflines = 0.
Also, you need to add the following code to change the height of the row according to the text inside it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return 0 }
    return cell.intrinsicContentSize.height
}
```

The intrinsicContentSize is the natural size for the receiving view, considering only properties of the view itself.